# adding click listener to iframe which is dynamically created in another iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used below code to add click event to iframe

```
$("#myframe").load(function() {
    $(this.contentWindow.document).on('click', function() {
      alert("works fine");
    });
  })
```

It works fine, but I need a click listener for inner iframe which is part of another iframe(parent #myframe).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736877/jquery-intercept-links-clicked-inside-an-iframe `$('#myiframe').contents().find("#container").delegate('a', 'click', function(e){ 
  //do stuff
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#myframe").load(function() {
    $(this.contentWindow.document).on('click', function() {
        alert('for parent')
    });

    $(this.contentWindow.document).find('iframe').contents().on('click', function() {
        alert('for inner iframe')
    });
})
```