# get the internal/inner links of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, iframe

I have website which includes some iframes, first thing that I have a website which contains only an Iframe. Let's call my website as www.example.com and the iframe inside that contains www.example2.com or it's a dynamic content, the iframe src will be changed when i change through admin cpanel. So i can get the src from there, my requirement is to get the sub links inside that iframed link. Suppose which contains an aboutus.html page, can i get that link using javascript/jquery or any other method?

Comment: Can't fully understand this...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736877/jquery-intercept-links-clicked-inside-an-iframe please refer this..

Comment: @ShafeequeShaz why don't you edit your question instead of post a comment. Will be better and will avoid down-votes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$("#bullUrl a").on("click",function(){

   //alert($(this).prop("href"));
   // or
   // alert($(this).attr("href"));

});
```